# mod_rewrite trailing slash for directory and remove for file url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-side

Ok. I got this problem I trying to remove the last slash in a file url for example `http://domain.com/styles/styles.css/`. I got the code for adding slash to the end but cannot figure how to do the conditional.

If the URL has an extesion then remove end slash
else add slash..

Here what I got right now some blogs says its the solution but still isn't working for what I expect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Also a problem, when I type `http://domain.com/index` it goes to `http://domain.com/inde/`.
Need your help guys.. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: By the way, why would anything be referring to `styles.css/` other than badly written HTML on that website itself? The only time you really need to fix slashes is for root pages like `http://example.com/coolproject`. Why don't you fix the HTML which is asking for a style sheet with an extra slash? By allowing `style.css/` to work, you're saying that it's okay to refer to a file as a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following code in your htaccess, for better understanding.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

I have a link : domain.com/folder/
it will change to : domain.com//folder
```

also You can turn off mod_dir's redirect by including a DirectorySlash Off.

Comment: same question like you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917542/remove-trailing-slash-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: What's the point of the cond?  It will *always* match as you will never get a domain "`.yourdomain.com`".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do an external redirect for such "furniture" files?  Surely an internal redirect is what you want here?

```
Options     -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$        $1         [L]
```

I advise that you turn off mutliviews if you don't use it as this can generate subrequests which confuse things.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteCond` conditions are logically inverted because you have the `!` operator there. So the rewrite is applying only for those inputs which do not have extensions, and which do not have a trailing slash!

You can do this with a single rule with no conditions:

```
# Match any sequence of characters, ending in a dot followed
# by one or more characters that don't contain dots or slashes,
# followed by a final trailing slash.
#
# Rewrite this absolutely and treat as redirect.

RewriteRule ^(.*\.[^./]+)/$ /$1 [L, R=301]
```